# RewriteRule works if Directory Exists

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following my .htacces file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(blog)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?blog=$2
RewriteRule ^(tag)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?tag=$2
```

when I have links that have an href to /blog/blog-title I get a 404 Not Found but when I click on links that have an href of /tag/tag-title it will display all my posts with that tag.  The strange thing is if I create a folder called blog in my main directory the /blog/blog-title will work!

Why is that and why do I have to do that for blog and not tag?

Answer (score 0):

The conditions only apply to the first rule. Rewrite conditions need to be repeated for each rule if you want them to be applied.

Though I'm not sure why it wasn't working initially, as `/blog/blot-title` doesn't exist in either case, you don't really need the conditions because the pattern is exclusive enough. You could actually just use a single rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(blog|tag)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?$1=$2 [L]
```

Comment: even with this it will do tag but it won't let me do blog unless I have a folder named blog in my main directory